# How do I gain access to an objects variable from another class?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I have looked around online and some things have helped but I am still yet to get this thing working. I am making a simple pong game but I want it so all my code is well set out. So I have a class for the player1 paddle, the computer paddle, the ball, the main screen and also the play screen.
So, for example, my player1Paddle class will have all the movement for that paddle, the computer paddle class(player2) will have all the movement for that and so on.
But when it comes to coding the simple AI of the computer paddle (basically follow the ball left to right) I am unable to get access to the balls position

```
if(player2Pong.position.x > ballPong.position.x)
```

It brings an error. Now i have instantiated the ball class and it works but I have basically made another ball but the movement is not there. Here are parts of the code to try and help. I know there's a lot of code, and probably some un-needed.
On my playScreen i call player2movement -

```
player2Pong.Player2Movement();
```

Heres the majority of the player2pong class.

```
 public class Player2Pong {
    public Vector2 position;    
    String textureLoc;
    Texture Player2Texture; 
    float stateTime;    
    Rectangle player2Bounds;    
    String movement;    
    int speed = 2;
    int playerXVector = 5;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    //PlayerPong playerpong;
    Player2Pong player2pong;

    Ball ballPong;

    public int paddle_player2_Width = 80;
    public int paddle_player2_Height = 10;

    //PlayerPong player;

    public Player2Pong(Vector2 position, Ball ball){

        Player2Texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(("paddle_player2.png")));
        this.position = position;       

        player2Bounds = new Rectangle(position.x,position.y,paddle_player2_Width, paddle_player2_Height);
        //this.player2pong = player2pong;   
        this.ballPong = ball;

    }

    public void update(){       

    }

public void Player2Movement(){  

    player2pong = new Player2Pong(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8)), ballPong); 

        System.out.println(player2pong.position.x);              

        if(player2pong.position.x > ballPong.getPosition().x){
            System.out.println("right");
            player2pong.position.x -= playerXVector;
        }

         else  if(player2pong.position.x < ballPong.getPosition().x){
            System.out.println("right");
            player2pong.position.x += playerXVector;
        }

         if(player2pong.position.x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - player2pong.getPaddle_player2_Width()-5){
             player2pong.position.x -= playerXVector;
         }

         if(player2pong.getPosition().x < 3){
             player2pong.position.x += playerXVector;
         }       

    }


public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){

        batch.draw(Player2Texture, position.x, position.y, paddle_player2_Width, paddle_player2_Height);            
    }
```

Here is majority of the playScreen class

```
  public class PlayScreenPong implements Screen{

    private static final Color WHITE = null;
    SpriteBatch batch;

    PlayerPong playerPong; 
    Player2Pong player2Pong;

    InputProcessor inputProcessor;  
    Game game;
    Ball ballPong;
    Texture paddle_player1, paddle_player2; 
    ArrayList<Ball> balls;  
    ArrayList<Player2Pong> player2;

    Iterator<Ball> ballsIterator;   
    Vector2 position;   
    ShapeRenderer borderSR, ballSR; 
    Sound sound;
    boolean rectangles = true;
    Stage PlayScreenStage;
    Label label;
    LabelStyle style;
    BitmapFont font;

    int playerXVector = 10;

    int player1Score = 0;
    int player2Score = 0;

    public PlayScreenPong(Game game){
        this.game = game;

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);       

        playerPong.update();
        //player2Pong.update();

        borderSR.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        borderSR.rect(1, 1, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-5, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-4);
        borderSR.setColor(1,1,1,1);
        borderSR.end();
        batch.begin();

        ballsIterator = balls.iterator();
        while(ballsIterator.hasNext()){
            Ball cur = ballsIterator.next();    
            cur.update();
            cur.draw(batch);            
        }       
        batch.draw(playerPong.getPlayerTexture(), playerPong.getPosition().x, playerPong.getPosition().y, playerPong.paddle_player1_Width, playerPong.paddle_player1_Height);   
        player2Pong.draw(batch);

        //batch.draw(player2Pong.getPlayer2Texture(), player2Pong.getPosition().x, player2Pong.getPosition().y, player2Pong.paddle_player2_Width, player2Pong.paddle_player2_Height);
        batch.end();
        score();


        PlayScreenStage.act();
        PlayScreenStage.draw();

        if(rectangles == true){
            ballPong.drawRectangle();
        }       
        player2Pong.Player2Movement();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        paddle_player1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("paddle_player1.png"));
        paddle_player2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("paddle_player2.png"));
        borderSR = new ShapeRenderer();     

        balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();
        player2 = new ArrayList<Player2Pong>();

        if(Gdx.files.local("paddle_player1.dat").exists()){
            try {
                playerPong = new PlayerPong(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8), "paddle_player1.png");
                playerPong.setPosition(PlayerPong.readPlayer());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("File exists, reading file");

        }else{
            playerPong = new PlayerPong(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 8),"paddle_player1.png");
            try {
                PlayerPong.savePlayer(playerPong);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Player doesnt exist, creating and saving player");                      
        }

//      player2Pong = new Player2Pong(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8)), playerPong);
//      player2.add(player2Pong);

        ballPong = new Ball(new Vector2(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2), playerPong);
        balls.add(ballPong);        
    }

    public void score(){        

        PlayScreenStage = new Stage();
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);
        style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);
        label = new Label("Player 1: " + player1Score + "  :  " + player2Score + " :Player 2", style);
        label.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - label.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/25);
        label.setFontScale((float) 0.8);

        PlayScreenStage.addActor(label);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(PlayScreenStage);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();  
        //System.out.println(ballPong.getPosition().y);

        //-------------------------------------if someone scores
        if(ballPong.getPosition().y< 1){
            player2Score = player2Score +1;
            //oppositionScore +=1;
            System.out.println("goal");
            //ballPong.reset();
        }

        if(ballPong.getPosition().y > Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-1 -ballPong.getBallSizeY()){
            player1Score = player1Score + 1;
            //ballPong.reset();
        }

    }
```

As I said before its a bit long winded but all I want to do is sort the movement of the AI in the player2pong class, the movement of the ball in the ball class and the movement of the player in the player class and then call the methods in the render or show methods in the playscreen class. Feel free to ask any questions. I know its an easy answer but im new :( Got to start somewhere

Comment: What's the specific error you are receiving?

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.Aaron.pong.PlayScreenPong.render(PlayScreenPong.java:83)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
 at com.Aaron.pong.pong.render(pong.java:22)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

Comment: And which line is 83 in PlayScreenPong?

Comment: player2Pong.draw(batch);

public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
  batch.draw(Player2Texture, position.x, position.y, paddle_player2_Width, paddle_player2_Height);   
 }

Comment: updated the bottom of the question

Comment: I don't see a `batch = new SpriteBatch(...);` This could be your problem.

Comment: where should this be put @MusicMaster ? cheers for the help again guys, appreciated

Comment: try the constructor of the class where the error occurs. Just replace the `...` with the appropriate parameters (if necessary).

Comment: no luck :( any other recommendations ? need anymore of the code ?

Comment: Paste the entirety of the classes.

Comment: also try putting `batch = new SpriteBatch(...);` in the constructor of the PlayScreen class.

Comment: @MusicMaster updated the question. put both full classes up :)

Comment: did you try moving `batch = new SpriteBatch(...);` to the constructor of the PlayScreenPong class?

Comment: yeah didnt work. its in the show method ??

Comment: try the beginning of the `render()` method.

Comment: actually it's probably better to put in `public PlayScreenPong(Game game)` (the constructor)

Comment: same error :/ have i forgotten to do something in the PLayer2pong class ?

Comment: what's with `position.x` and `position.y` in the last line of Player2Pong class?

Comment: drawing the sprite / texture ?

Comment: also you might want to try uncommenting those two lines in the `show` method.

Comment: think that helped :) changed the player2pong to ballPong. now i have an error - player2Pong.Player2Movement();

Comment: did you modify those two lines when you uncommented them?

Comment: yeah it brought up an error. so i changed the player2pong to ballPong as im taking in a ball in the constructor of the player2pong class. Now the error is pointing to this -

if(position.x > ballPong.getPosition().x){
   System.out.println("right");
   position.x -= playerXVector;
  }

think it cant find the value of the ballpong.x position. any ideas ?

Comment: Also There is also no reason to have a `Player2Pong` variable in the `Player2Pong` class. Just replace all the instances of `player2Pong` with the word `this` (at least in the `Player2Pong` class)

Comment: Oh and in libgdx don't use `System.out.println()`

Comment: im only using it to test it in the console. this stupid thing still isnt working lol

Comment: If you're having this many problems maybe you should just leave it be for a few hours and come back to it. And, judging by your code, it seems you're pretty new to java. It might be worth taking a few weeks to properly learn java (look for good tutorials on the web).

Comment: yeah i do need the practice. thanks for the help :)

Comment: found out whats wrong. the ballPong was giving a null value in the Player2Pong class. any idea on how to fix that ? i cant access the getPosition from the ballPong @MusicMaster

Comment: SOLVED! I made the balls array before the player2 array but i made a new player2 paddle before i made the ball. So when i wanted to change the player2 x co-ordinate in relation to the ball it had no ball to follow :) thanks everyone for your help :) @MusicMaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so, I might be wrong with this, but it's worth a shot.

First off, you don't need to create a new `Player2pong` object every time you call the `PlayerMovement()` function, you already have one:P

Secondly, you never make assign anything to the `player2Pong` attribute. So when you try and call `draw()` on it, there's nothing to call it on!:P

Comment: found out whats wrong. the ballPong was giving a null value in the Player2Pong class. any idea on how to fix that ?

Comment: Yes, you also never initialise that in the player2Pong object.